# Hidde Button/Label from Web query

Tags: iphone, button, label

how can I hide a Button/label if a specific file on server is available? (e.g: www.google.com/test/test.xls)

So if test.xls is there then the Button/label should be hidden?

Nils

Comment: Where is the code you are using to test the file? Are you  working iOS or web?did you even try anything?

Comment: That is the question how can I check the file? iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its really simple. Use this code

```
if (<File Found> == YES)
{
    button.hidden = YES;
    label.hidden = YES;
}
else
{
    button.hidden = NO;
    label.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: OK thanks, but who can I check if the File is found?

Comment: you can find it by hitting an api that can return u a BOOL variable. This is a server side Operation you cant do it in Client Side. To get information about file is availabel in server or not, u have to write a web service, and call that service with respective file name.

Comment: OK thanks for quick replay. For my understanding: e.g. the file is a .pdf can i try to open the pdf in background(invisible) if the file can be opened the file is there if i get a error the file is not there?